# Trackable custom anchors in ARKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, aranchor

Is there a way to create a custom anchor with ARKit that is trackable? I am trying to build and AR app and put an anchor on a moving 3D object and have a scenekit node render on that object. For example, can a create an anchor on someone's hand/leg/toe/dog/ball (without a VNHandPoseRequest) that conforms to ARTrackable? I have a model that gives me the exact 3D location of this initial anchor and that is how I plan of initializing it, but now I need a way to track that 3D point in realtime in an ARScene.